# How can I see if a string is four letters long? – Windows Batch

Tags: regex, windows, for-loop, batch-file

So I'm working on a Windows Batch script and I want to know if an input string (the name of a file) is exactly four letters long. I want to do it with regular expressions or string matching.

I tried the following but it didn't work...

```
for /R "%windir%\system32" %%f in (*) do (
    set filename=%%~nf

    if not "!filename!"=="!filename:[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]=!" (
        echo %%~nf
    )
)
```

So my code loops through all the files in \system32. The files like mode.com should be echoed, but it's not the case.

Comment: In your code, `If /I "%%~nf"=="!filename:~,4!" Echo %%~nf` should echo the four letter basenames. Although if your intent is to just find files with four letter basenames, there are better ways of doing that.

Comment: @Compo 
It echoes names with 4 letters but also names with less than 4... Is there a way to specify only four letters?

Comment: ElonTheFreemason, I note that you've accepted an answer which does not match the question you posted. Your question specifically was recursively searching, whereas that answer does not. It's a little unfair to select an answer which doesn't match your requirements, when other answers have tried to do so. Also, the answer you've accepted does not correctly identify all files with four alphabetic character basenames, only those with four alphabetic characters followed by a period. This essentially means that it ignores extensionless files. Please see my answer which caters both of these factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
dir /B "%windir%\system32" | findstr "^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]\."
```

Tested on Windows 10

Comment: Yes, this is the quickest way to achieve this indeed. tested now on Windows 10 and 8.1 `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Aacini's answer is the best when no recursion is required.

Just in case you need something more flexible (but way slower):

```
@echo off
for /R "%windir%\system32" %%f in (*) do (
  echo %%~nf|findstr /rix "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]" >nul && (
    echo %%~ff has a 4 letter filename: %%~nf and a size of %%~zf Bytes
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As implied in my comment, and assuming four characters, not four alphabetic characters:

```bat
@For /R "%__AppDir__%" %%A In (*)Do @(Set "FN=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not "%%~nA"=="!FN:~,3!" If "%%~nA"=="!FN:~,4!" Echo %%~nA
    EndLocal)
```

And here's a possible alternative, for four alphabetic characters. Run it 'As administrator' if you're really trying to parse all files inside `\Windows\System32\`, *(not essential but may pick up more files)*:

```bat
@Dir /B/S/A-D "%__AppDir__%" 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "\\[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]\.[^\.]*$ \\[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]$"
```

You could put that inside a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) if, for some inexplicable reason, you only want only the basenames:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=?Tokens=*" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "%__AppDir__%" 2^>NUL^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "\\[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]\.[^\.]*$ \\[a-Z][a-Z][a-Z][a-Z]$"')Do @Echo(%%~nA
```

Comment: Nice - you gave both solutions that I thought of. I think it would be better to use `[^\.]` instead of `[a-z]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dir /b C:\Windows\system32 | findstr /r "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]"
```

The problem in your code was regular expression using style. You need to use `findstr` for regular expressions.

Comment: This finds all filenames with at least four letters in the name or extension, but the question was about exactly four.