# Batch command to find files containing specific characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm looking for a command that allows me in my `%windir%\system32` to get all files that contains 4 characters and the second letter of all those characters must be `i`

All I was able to found by myself is that command:

```
 >dir /r %windir%\system32 |findstr /b ".i.*\.dll"
```

Comment: Why is the command that you have not what you want?

Comment: The command that I managed to found doesn't work it does not provide me what I'm looking for

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is actually descriptive about the question you're asking or problem you're having. Your current title conveys zero meaning, as *batch command* is specified by the [tag:batch-file] tag, and it's clear you need *help* or you wouldn't be posting here. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to a future reader who is searching for a problem solution and scanning a list of search results. Your current one doesn't work for that purpose. While you're making that edit, you can explain the problem with the code you posted and ask a question.

Comment: "get all files that contains 4 characters" - do you mean the file should contain four characters, or the filename should contain four characters?

Answer (score 1):

You question, is not specific enough, and bears an almost striking similarity to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58599651) posed yesterday. So other than [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606918) yesterday, and based upon your second character stipulation here are two examples of commands which may do what you require:

This will output the names of all four character `.dll` files within your `\System32` directory whose second character is `i` or `I`:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%where.exe" "%__AppDir__%.":?i??.dll
```

The following should output the names of all files anywhere within your `\System32` directory which have a four character basename with the second character being `i` or `I`:

```bat
Dir /B/A-D "%__AppDir__%"|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I "^.i..\.[^\.]*$ ^.i..$"
```

If you want something more specific or less generic, you should change your question to fully explain what you're trying to find or exclude from any search results.